# How to remove unnecessary bands from .sid file (keeping file format)

Tags: geoserver, multi-band, band, mrsid

An ImageMosaic layer created from .sid data containing 5 bands has black areas where data is missing and setting transparency parameter in GeoServer does not help as error appears:

```
Error rendering coverage on the fast path
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BandCombine: a row of the matrix does not have the correct number of entries, should be OpImage.getExpandedNumBands(source0.getSampleModel(), source0.getColorModel()) + 1.
BandCombine: a row of the matrix does not have the correct number of entries, should be OpImage.getExpandedNumBands(source0.getSampleModel(), source0.getColorModel()) + 1.
```

Tried adding

```
<RasterSymbolizer>
    <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
    <ChannelSelection>
        <RedChannel>
            <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>
        </RedChannel>
        <GreenChannel>
            <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName>
        </GreenChannel>
        <BlueChannel>
            <SourceChannelName>3</SourceChannelName>
        </BlueChannel>
    </ChannelSelection>
</RasterSymbolizer>
```

to the layer style but no result

`gdal_translate -b ... in.sid out.sid` can not output .sid files and outputs .tiff instead making data set larger which is undesirable

Comment: GDAL will not write MRSID files, its driver is *read only*. If you omit the -ot argument of GDAL_Translate the default is GeoTIFF which it wont like because you've specified the output as .sid. Stick with GeoTIFF and put up with the size of the file or contact the company that owns the rights to MRSID to purchase a compressor.

Comment: see http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html

Comment: What version of GeoServer is that? With GeoServer 2.14.x we have been publishing 4, 13 and 200+ bands (hyperspectral) datasets